# Azure Server name not found

Tags: azure-mysql-database

I followed the tutorial as mentioned on the website "Create Azure database"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal

Still while trying to connect to the database from local cmd it gives me this error:-

> ERROR 9002 (28000): The server name you tried cannot be found. Please use the correct name and retry. Please check your server name eztolluser1.

I am trying for the past two days but in vain.

Comment: Have you tried to ping the hostname from your machine? If the ping fails with no IP address on the messages, looks like a DNS resolution problem. If you can get the IP address of the server in Azure, try using the address directly instead of hostname.

Comment: Ping does not fail but using the same hostname also gives the same error. Thanks for commenting though.